# Bound app scripts and multiple projects

Tags: google-apps-script

First time I'm working with google app scripts. I inherited a google sheet (template) from a colleague (who no longer works with us) that runs some scripts on change. The script from what I read should be a **bound** script.

When I open Script editor though, I see 2 projects. One is the copy of an earlier version of the project.  Each of them has an onOpen() function. My question is how does the sheet know which one to invoke?

To replicate the behaviour, I created a sheet of my own and then using the script editor, created two projects each with the onOpen function. The function adds some menus on opening the sheet.
I see that both functions are fired, because the menu names are different. However, I don't see the same behaviour in the original template in question which seems to invoke only one of the two scripts.

I checked to see if there are any triggers etc. but none seem to exist. I find no documentation around this either.

Comment: You may want to check [Scripts Bound to Google Sheets, Docs, or Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to fully understand the behavior of bound scripts. It also gives some insights on special methods, use of custom menus, dialogs, and sidebars. It also mentioned about the use of simple triggers or installable triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both bounded to the sheet, as your tests showed both onOpen(e) are being invoked. What you could do to know which of the script was edited last or some details is to check the revision history of each script (in each script file-> see revision history).

I figure the last developer didn't comment the code so he must've disaled one of them by hand

Answer (score 0):

It turns out as I mentioned that both onOpen functions were indeed being fired. Both scripts and tons of code in it but was exactly identical and the end effect was the same on the sheet. Pretty weird.

I fixed it by making a copy of the sheet which let me delete one of the projects and keep just one. I then deleted the original sheet and made my copy the official one (naming it the same).

I'd have preferred if apps script chose to make it unambiguous by mandating explicit triggers to a function on a particular sheet.